# Using lzo compression in java

Tags: java, compression, lzo

I am trying to use LZO compression in java. Is there a suitable library to do this. I tried lzo-java, however it seems to be really really slow as compared to gzip. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: try lz4.java. Not sure about performance related to gzip and lzo.

Comment: tried lz4 unfortunately our implementation of hadoop uses lzo or gzip and I am stuck with using one of the 2 algorithms.

Comment: @Rohit- Have you ever tried lzo-java library? please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397397/how-to-decompress-lzo-compressed-byte-array-in-java and give me your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use LZO jar file and can be downloaded from given link 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadooplzo0414jar.htm

It will help you